# Implement A Function

Tags: abstract-algebra, computer-science

Group $G = Z_p^*$ Where $p$ is the order of $G$. $e$ is a funtion $e : G \times G \to G $ such that:

1. (Bilinear) For all $P,Q \in G$, for all $a,b \in Z$, $e(P^a,Q^b) = e(P,Q)^{ab}$.
2. (Non-degenerate) There exists some $P, Q \in G$ such that $e(P, Q)\neq 1$, where $1$ is the identity of $G$.

How to implement such function $e$ in Computer(Java)?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is there only one such function?  And what's the $*$ mean?

Comment: @EnjoysMath I believe there are many functions fit in these two rules, but I cannot find even one. The '*' means it only contains non-negative numbers.For example if p = 4, the $Z_p^*$ means a group contains 0, 1, 2, 3

Comment: OK, I myself find out one.It's quite simple. When e is pow(or say times in Congruence plus group), the two  conditions are fit.